# Can Renderscript use Pixel Visual core?

Tags: renderscript, android-renderscript

The new Pixel Visual core seems promising for imaging applications. Official blog mentions halide and TensorFlow to program this special processor but not renderscript. Will Renderscript (given its original goal) leverage this processor?

https://www.blog.google/products/pixel/pixel-visual-core-image-processing-and-machine-learning-pixel-2/

Answer (score 0):

Since renderscript runs on DSPs if available, it should run on the pixel visual core since its activation on Android 8.1